# Allegro CL Lisp editor

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

In Allegro CL Free Express Edition, how do I load the last LISP command in the Debug window? I am looking for similar things to an up arrow in the terminal.

Comment: I don't have Allegro handy, but some IDEs have keybindings similar to Emacs or a some Unix shells.  Ctrl-P or Alt-P might help.

Comment: You can see the shortcuts by moving the mouse over the debug window's toolbar buttons.